# How to Abbreviate camel-case text string in TypeScript / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, text-manipulation

I have some large table.column names that need to be abbreviated. Or rather the table names need to be abbreviated.

Take the following examples of table.col names, and what they should look like:

```
agentByState5Minutes.agentId ----> aBS5M.agentId
contactReasonByMail.agentName -----> cRBM.agentName
```

As you can see above the table names are a mixture of casing and numbers. In my function I have split the table name from the column name to make it easier:

```
protected columnNameConvert(colName: string): string{
    this.log.info('columnNameConvert:colName:'+ colName);
    let colNameSplit: Array<string> = colName.split('.');
    let tableName: string = colNameSplit[0];
    let realColName: string = colNameSplit[1];

    return colName;
}
```

Can the tableName be abbreviated using regex text manipulation perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `replace` to match anything that isn't a capital letter, a number, or at the beginning of the string, while looking ahead for a `.` and (at the beginning) checking that the position is not at the start of the string:

```js
const change = str => str.replace(
  /(?!^)[^A-Z\d](?=[^.]*\.)/g,
  ''
);
console.log(
  change('agentByState5Minutes.agentId'), // ----> aBS5M.agentId
  change('contactReasonByMail.agentName') // -----> cRBM.agentName
);
```

`(?!^)[^A-Z\d](?=[^.]*\.)` means:

- `(?!^)` - Negative lookahead for the beginning of the string (make sure this position matched is not at the start of the string)
- `[^A-Z\d]` - Anything but an uppercase letter or digit
- `(?=[^.]*\.)` - Make sure that the matched character is eventually followed by a `.`

In Typescript syntax:

```
const columnNameConvert = (colName: string) => colName.replace(
  /(?!^)[^A-Z\d](?=[^.]*\.)/g,
  '',
);
```

(remember that there's no need to explicitly denote the return type if TS can infer it for itself)

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a slight mod to the original question, if I wanted to keep just the first word in the camelcase table name how do I do this? example:  `agentByState5Minutes.agentId //----> agentBS5M.agentId`

Comment: Capture the initial word and alternate with the rest of the pattern, and replace with the captured group (which will be the empty string after the first match): [`^([a-z]+)|[^A-Z\d](?=[^.]*\.)`](https://regex101.com/r/Qvi7lo/1)